# How to separate time value from a full Date in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to separate only time value by using the Date() function. But not able to do it. Below is the code that I am using:

```
var currentDate = serviceObj.ActivityDate();
var priorityMonth = GetMembershipMonthsArray();

var membershipEndYear = GetMembershipEndYear();

var actYear = currentActivityDate.getFullYear();
var actMonth = MONTH_NAMES[currentActivityDate.getMonth()];
var actMonthIndex = jQuery.inArray(actMonth, priorityMonth);

var maxDate = new Date(Date.parse(priorityMonth[11] + " 1, " + membershipEndYear));
maxDate.setMonth(maxDate.getMonth() + 1);
maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate() - 1);
```

I am getting the **maxDate** value without the time. So, I tried using **maxDate.setTime(value)** as well. but I cant fetch the "value" part(only time value")

The currentDate is **Tue Dec 20 09:53:36 UTC+0530 2016**. How can I fetch only the time. i.e  **09:53:36**.

I tried using **currentDate.split(' ')[2]**, but it threw me an error as split is not defined or something else.....

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to separate only time value by using the Date() function

```
var dt=new Date();
dt.getHours() +":"+ dt.getMinutes() +":"+dt.getSeconds()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
var date = currentDate.split(/[- :]/); 
// currentDate = Tue Dec 20 09:53:36 UTC+0530 2016

var time = date[3] + ':' + date[4] + ':' + date[5];
// time is equal to 09:53:36
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "Tue Dec 20 09:53:36 UTC+0530 2016";
var patt = /[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/g;
var result = patt.exec(str);
```